# Python: Check for Negative Numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to add a piece of code to this string to check for a negative number in the first position. If the code identifies a negative number it should return "False". I'm having trouble with int and str at the user input command. Sorry, new to Python.

```
def is_number(S):
    #if s < 0:
        #print("False")
    #else:   
        try:
            float(s)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            pass

        try:
            import unicodedata
            unicodedata.numeric(s)
            return True
        except (TypeError, ValueError):
            pass
        return False

s = input()

is_number(s)
```

Comment: The above code should accept numeric and alpha inputs without throwing an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
def check_negative(s):
    try:
        f = float(s)
        if (f < 0):
            return True
        # Otherwise return false
        return False
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Not entirely sure if this is what you want though, maybe you should see ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000's answer

Comment: "to check for a negative number in the first position". What if it is a string that contains a float with characters after it?

Comment: I was able to make this work! I used the "try" portion of this code and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
is_number=lambda S: str(S)[0]=='-' and len(str(S))>1
```

Try this code. You can replace your `is_number` function with this code. It is a function which checks whether the first character is a negative sign, and if it is, it will return true. Otherwise, the number cannot be negative, and it will then return false. However, if there is only a `-` sign, then it is neither and will return false. It only uses one line and is much simpler. It works for strings and floats too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.