# what is the error in this program. for finding positive or negative number in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = int(input("Enter a number"))
#get input from the user as integer
z = x % 2
#store the input in z and find mod by 2
if z == -1:
#to find positive or negative
    print("negative")
else:
    print("positive")
```

Comment: `z` is never negative. It's 0 for even `x` and 1 for odd `x` (even if `x` is negative).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Check for Negative Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48677065/python-check-for-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You may expect that the modulo operator gives you also negative numbers as possible results. But this is not the default case in Python, [see the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) *(emphasis mine)*:

> The modulo operator always yields a result **with the same sign as its second operand** (or zero)

```py
-5 % 2  # outputs: 1
```

So you have basically two choices *(with my preferred order)*:

1. Compare against zero (It is readable and simple, perhaps it's the most understandable code – also valid in other languages.):

   ```py
   x = int(input("Enter a number"))
   if x >= 0:
       print("positive")
   else:
       print("negative")
   ```
2. Check if the string representation of the converted number starts with a minus sign (It's also quite simple, but more complex than version 1.):

   ```py
   x = int(input("Enter a number"))
   if str(x).startswith("-"):
       print("negative")
   else:
       print("positive")
   ```

There is also a third choice, using `math.fmod` to get a similar behaviour as in other languages for the modulo operator:

1. Compare against `0`:

   ```py
   import math
   x = int(input("Enter a number"))
   z = math.fmod(x, 2)
   if z == 0:
       print("positive")
   else:
       print("negative")
   ```
2. Compare against `-1`:

   ```py
   import math
   x = int(input("Enter a number"))
   z = math.fmod(x, 2)
   if z == -1:
       print("negative")
   else:
       print("positive")
   ```

So, this is the most similar code in comparison to your provided code. But both code snippets would lead to unwanted behaviour. This is because Python implemented the IEEE 754 standard, so that there is no difference between `0` and `-0`. That means that there is no easy way to ensure that this code is working as expected, as described in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Comparisons), for example:

> According to the IEEE 754 standard, negative zero and positive zero should compare as equal with the usual (numerical) comparison operators, like the == operators of C and Java. In those languages, special programming tricks may be needed to distinguish the two values […]